# Javascript local variables into global variables

Tags: javascript

I tried a solution presented in several other topics here, but for some reason, it doesn't work for me

```
$(function() {
$('.talk').live('click', 'button', function()
{
var user1 = $(this).val();
var user2=$(this).prev().val();
window.user=user1;
window.recipient=user2;

})
})
```

(...)

```
console.log(window.user);
var refresh = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
function myTimer() {loadchat(window.user,window.recipient);
}
function myStopFunction() {clearInterval(refresh);}
```

I need the function loadchat to receive the parameters user1 and user2, but they are confined withing the first function i pasted here. I read that if i use window.user1= it will work, but it won't.

The way it is right now, the console.log(window.user) will return "undefined" (i also tried just "user" instead of window.user)

Comment: *"the console.log(window.user) will return "undefined""* I'm pretty sure that `console.log(window.user)` gets executed **before** `.talk` is clicked. `window.user=user1;` will be executed *some time in the future*. `console.log(window.user)`  is executed on page load.

Comment: Note that `function(){ myTimer() }` can be just `myTimer`.

Comment: You can either define your variable outside the function or define it on the window object

Comment: @Felix Kling
I think you're right. however i tried to prevent that creating a second function that would also be triggered by .talk. Such function would trigger the setInterval but at some point things will not work because of this local/global variable issue. Maybe the myStopFunction will not understand what refresh is. I can try rearranging things but the elements will never fit in a way that it works. I think the solution would only be possible by solving this global/local thing
In the end, it's pointless. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Define your global value outside the function

```
<script>
var globalVariable;
function()
{
   globalVariable = $(this).val();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. And why should that work instead of what the OP is currently doing?

Answer (score 0):

what I can understood of your question is this 
you need a way to store user and recipient

You can use this

```
$(function() {
$('.talk').live('click', 'button', function() {
   var user1 = $(this).val();
   var user2=$(this).prev().val();

   localStorage.setItem("User", user1);
   localStorage.setItem("recipient", user2);
  })
})
```

can retrieve your data with the function
`localStorage.getItem("User");`

but this is problematic because the data will stay remain in memory after close the tab
to solve this you need to use sessions vars

```
sessionStorage.setItem("User", user1);
sessionStorage.getItem("User");
```